# Q: Drupal 8.8.x install errors

Tags: drupal-8

I just installed a Drupal 8 sight (ddev composer drupal/recommended-project) and am getting the following error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for 
"GET /" (from "https://webwash.ddev.site/core/install.php? 
langcode=en&profile=standard") in 
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest() (line 
137 of /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php).
Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->matchRequest(Object) (Line: 113)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object, 
'kernel.request', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.request', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher- 
>dispatch('kernel.request', Object) (Line: 127)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 694)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Not sure where to go next.

Comment: I truncated all the cache_ tables and the errors seem to have gone away

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested rebuilding caches from the command line as opposed to performing truncate directly on your DB, but if it worked, great.